# Plone root folder for Let's Encrypt

Tags: ubuntu, plone, lets-encrypt

I just installed Let's encrypt on my Ubuntu VPS running Plone and in order to setup the webroot plugin for auto renewal I need to know where the webroot folder for my plone instance is so I can create the '.well-known' folder.

I installed Plone using the zcluster option under /usr/local/Plone

Comment: Are you running a proper webserver in front of Plone (i.e. nginx, httpd, …)? My gut reaction would be to exempt the `.well-known` folder from being forwarded to Plone in the first place. (In httpd, that'd be `ProxyPass /.well-known !`.)

Comment: Thank You Ulrich, I do have Nginx so I will look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plone for production use should be installed with a reverse-proxy server like Nginx or Apache that handles connections on the http and https ports. That reverse proxy is going to be the one handling your TSL/SSL connections and certificates.

What you want to do is have your well-known folder be handled by Nginx or Apache via tailored rewrite rules. Done this way, the whole TLS/SSL part of the stack is separated from Zope/Plone.

Comment: Thank You, I will do that as I have Nginx in front of it.